# Open file with my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using  to open files that the user get in mail with my app :

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>RTF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.rtf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

there is a problem that when the app come from the background it won't call :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

so where i get the notification about the file that opend with my app?

Comment: hi, i have a similar problem with you, but i need to open all file types that user get in mail with my app. I have implement a code like yours, and also - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url; in my app delegate..

i can open text file, but i cant open zip file from mail into my app, can you give me some clue? what i have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app comes out of the background to handle a file open, openURL will be called instead of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions here's the full signature:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```